# App name showing as blank when running on iOS device Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to prepare an update for an app I created, but when I go to run the app on my phone, it appears with no name. Nothing has changed as far as bundle identification goes, but last night Xcode started to say that no valid provisioning profile was found for the executable, so in fixing that I may have broken the name. Any ideas as to what would fix this?

Comment: so when you go to your apps .plist what's the value for the key 'Bundle display name'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the 'Bundle display name' in the appname-Info.plist to ${PRODUCT_NAME} or the string you want.

Hope it helped!

Comment: ...that was what was causing the issue. Thank you very much!